# Replicating Hexagon heatmap in ggmaps [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, heatmap, ggspatial

I need to replicate [heatmap](/questions/tagged/heatmap) that can be found in the link: https://rpubs.com/chrisbrunsdon/gwdplyr

I tried the very approach however I cannot replicate final hexagon colored heatmap.

My main issues is that I am having problem with even creating non colored map, using `st_buffer(), st_make_grid()` for some reason it takes a lot of time and then cannot be store because the file is very large.

I provided example that is with location that I need to plot `heatmap` on, then values are discrete and shall be use as color in `heatmap`

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)


df <- 
  data.frame(
  x = runif(1000, min = 14.22, max = 14.71),
  y = runif(1000, min = 49.94, max = 50.18),
  value = sample(c(1:8))
)

hp <- 
  df%>%
  st_as_sf(coords=c("x","y"),crs=27700) 


gl_hexes <- st_buffer(hp,1) %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize=c(0.0005, 0.0005),square=FALSE) %>% 
  st_sf() %>% mutate(hex_ID=sprintf('Hex%04d',row_number()))
```

I will be thankful for any advice...

Comment: Have you tried this with a larger cell size?

Comment: Can you please provide example

Comment: Try the map with `st_make_grid(cellsize=c(0.05, 0.05),square=FALSE)`. Smaller the cell size greater the number of calculations thus the large file size.